# VBA If/Then based on Record Count

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, eof, record-count

I'd like to create an If/Then statement in VBA where if there are multiple records in the recordset one message populates, and if there is only record another message populates.

Right now I'm using

```
If rst.EOF = False Then...

Else ...

End If
```

This is only returning the first condition regardless of how many records are in the recordset though.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to count the records:

```
If rst.EOF = False Then
    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst
    If rst.RecordCount = 1 Then
        ' One record.
    Else
        ' More records.
    End If
Else
    ' No records.
End If
```

Comment: I'm actually getting the same result--even though I had two records in the table, the output is still in the format of rst.RecordCount = 1.

Comment: Then your query for the recordset only returns one record, or the recordset is of a type that doesn't return the record count. If so, loop the records and count until EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your recordset, `.MoveLast` can severely impact on performance and since `.RecordCount` will not yield the total number of records, but rather the number of *accessed* records, a call to `.MoveLast` is required.

To offer an alternative, consider the following:

```
If rst.EOF Then
    ' No records
Else
    rst.MoveFirst
    rst.MoveNext
    If rst.EOF Then
        ' 1 record
    Else
        ' More than 1 record
    End If
End If
```

This first tests whether the recordset is already at `.EOF`, and if so, there are no records in the recordset.

If we have some records, it moves the cursor to the first record (`.MoveFirst`), and then to the next record (`.MoveNext`) if it exists.

If we have now reached `.EOF`, there must be only one record in the recordset; else, there are more records.

Since you only need to branch for the case there is a single record, this method means you are accessing the minimum number of records to determine this condition.